# Preparing cheat sheets

Tags: document-classes, templates

Are there any templates, document classes for preparing cheat sheets?

If not, what would make it easy to produce such documents?

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911516/how-to-make-cheat-sheets-in-latex) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165812/writing-formula-sheets-cheat-sheet-in-lyx-latex) threads at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is what I'm using for small cheat sheets. It is derived from some sheet I found out there, unfortunately, I cannot recall whom should I credit... Anyway, there you go:

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{color,graphicx,overpic}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\pdfinfo{
  /Title (example.pdf)
  /Creator (TeX)
  /Producer (pdfTeX 1.40.0)
  /Author (Seamus)
  /Subject (Example)
  /Keywords (pdflatex, latex,pdftex,tex)}

% This sets page margins to .5 inch if using letter paper, and to 1cm
% if using A4 paper. (This probably isn't strictly necessary.)
% If using another size paper, use default 1cm margins.
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest { \paperwidth = 11in}}
    { \geometry{top=.5in,left=.5in,right=.5in,bottom=.5in} }
    {\ifthenelse{ \lengthtest{ \paperwidth = 297mm}}
        {\geometry{top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm} }
        {\geometry{top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm} }
    }

% Turn off header and footer
\pagestyle{empty}

% Redefine section commands to use less space
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}%
                                {-1ex plus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
                                {0.5ex plus .2ex}%x
                                {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0mm}%
                                {-1explus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
                                {0.5ex plus .2ex}%
                                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0mm}%
                                {-1ex plus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
                                {1ex plus .2ex}%
                                {\normalfont\small\bfseries}}
\makeatother

% Define BibTeX command
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

% Don't print section numbers
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.5ex}

%My Environments
\newtheorem{example}[section]{Example}
% -----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\raggedright
\footnotesize
\begin{multicols}{3}


% multicol parameters
% These lengths are set only within the two main columns
%\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.25pt}
\setlength{\premulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\postmulticols}{1pt}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{2pt}

\begin{center}
     \Large{\underline{Title}} \\
\end{center}

\section{Section 1}
Text
\subsection{xCode}
Subsetction text

\section{Section 2}
Text 2

\section{Section 3}
Etc.

% You can even have references
\rule{0.3\linewidth}{0.25pt}
\scriptsize
\bibliographystyle{abstract}
\bibliography{refFile}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

I hope you'd find it useful.

Comment: Wow, looks like what I am looking for, and easy to understand. I will try it out.

Comment: I think it's from this cheat sheet, which is also a good resource to learn something from: http://stdout.org/~winston/latex/

Comment: @bereqn The stdout link is broken.

Comment: Updated link: https://wch.github.io/latexsheet/.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look as to how this [cheatsheet](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/cheat.pdf) was made. The source can be downloaded at 
[TeX showcase](http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/). If this is too difficult, just try the following minimal with pdfTeX.

```
... your equations here
\bye
```

Comment: That cheat sheet was my inspiration, and it was too difficult for a rookie like me :) `minimal` documentclass has too wide margins too, I want to use all the space I can.

Comment: @nimcap What type of cheat sheet do you want to typeset?

Comment: Like the one you posted. As I and you said it is a little bit difficult to understand and modify. If there was a template/document class to make it easier...

Comment: @nimcap Here is a suggestion - structure it first. Write what you want to include - use article class and 3-column with multicolumn. then post any difficulties you have. Alternative one long table with `longtable`.

Comment: I've got no idea what you want to tell the OP with your TeX code block.

Comment: May the author rest in peace!

Answer (score 11):

I suggest you to use a long table of minipages. Each cell is made from a minipage. And a minipage can support almost everything.

But, don't put too long object because minipage cannot be broken between pages.

## Edit 1

You can also nest a `\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}` inside `\begin{longtable}...\end{longtable}` to partition the parent cell.

## Edit 2

If you use nested table approach, it is better to put the child table in a separate file and import it from your parent cell using `\input{}`. This method will make the parent table cleaner and easy to maintain in the future.

[image]

```
\documentclass[table,cmyk]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array,calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ratio[2]{\strip@pt\dimexpr#1pt/#2\relax}
\newcolumntype{A}[2]
{
        >{\begin{minipage}[t]{#2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-#1\arrayrulewidth}%
        \vspace{\tabcolsep}}%
        c%
        <{\vspace{\tabcolsep}\end{minipage}}%   
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}

\arrayrulewidth=1pt
\tabcolsep=10pt
\arrayrulecolor{red}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}
{
    |A{1.5}{\ratio{30}{100}}% 30%
    |A{1}{\ratio{30}{100}}% 30%
    |A{1.5}{\ratio{40}{100}}% 40%
    |%
}\hline
%Cell 1,1
The fundamental theorem of calculus,
\[
\int_a^b f(x)\,\textrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a)
\]
where \[\frac{\textrm{d}F(x)}{\textrm{d}x}=f(x)\]
&
%Cell 1,2
\LaTeX\ will make you confident!
&
%Cell 1,3
\lipsum[1]
\tabularnewline\hline
%Cell 2,1
The fundamental theorem of calculus,
\[
\int_a^b f(x)\,\textrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a)
\]
where \[\frac{\textrm{d}F(x)}{\textrm{d}x}=f(x)\]
&
%Cell 2,2
\LaTeX\ will make you confident!
&
%Cell 2,3
\lipsum[2]
\tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Even though this question is 3 years old, I think I should mention the `cheatsheet` class, which is inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36768704) answer on another question. It is available via [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cheatsheet) and developed on [GitHub](https://github.com/ACHinrichs/LaTeX-templates/tree/master/cheatsheet)

Comment: Indeed, I am the author