# Is this layout feasible in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

I run a [cheat sheet website](http://www.cheatography.com), and at the moment producing PDFs of the cheat sheets is a nightmare. I would like to find an easier system, and I'm wondering if LaTeX might be it. I've not used LaTeX a lot, though I do find it very useful when I do use it, so I've not got the experience to be able to tell if LaTeX can handle the kind of layout I need to reproduce.

Enough waffling ... this is how the cheat sheets are laid out:

http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/pdf/

Can anybody tell me if LaTeX could handle this kind of layout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8827/preparing-cheat-sheets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks simple. You want

- a threecolumn layout: Use `multicol`
- colors: Use `xcolor`
- some kind of sections: Use `tabular` together with `xcolor`