# How can I do this page?

Tags: beamer, math-mode, beamerposter

I'm a teacher math and I will give to my students a sheet with a mathematical summary (resume). I'm thinking in this model, but with other matter. How can I do this page? Thank you.[image]

Comment: As far as stacking the sub-blocks, these are related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122062/placing-textblock-or-equivalent-in-same-seperation/122073#122073 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123284/cheatsheet-template/123295#123295

Comment: and `beamerposter` ( you don't need to print it on A0)

Comment: The key question is how closely does it have to fit the example?  Square frames are less work then rounded corners.  Since the text doesn't wrap, you can use three minipages for the basic layout and parboxes or smaller minipages for each section.  Tikz for the diagrams, tabulars for the tables, etc.  If you want to color the backgrounds, and lot of Tikz.

Comment: use one of the templates given in [How to create posters using LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341)

Comment: I've had good luck using the `fancytikzposter` as a template to base my posters on: http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/fancytikzposter.html

Comment: Just remember that you can use (almost) any TeX command inside a node text field, including \begin{tikzpicture}