# Split equation problem in cheatsheet?

Tags: equations, minipage

I was trying to prepare a cheat sheet using the template posted by xport ([Preparing cheat sheets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8827/preparing-cheat-sheets))

However when I try to use "\begin{split}" I get an error

> \begin{split} on input line...ended by \end{minipage}

However, if I use eqnarray it works fine. I wonder why "split" option does not work.

Below is my code,

```
\documentclass[table,cmyk]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array,calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ratio[2]{\strip@pt\dimexpr#1pt/#2\relax}
\newcolumntype{A}[2]
{
    >{\begin{minipage}[t]{#2\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-#1\arrayrulewidth}%
    \vspace{\tabcolsep}}%
    c%
    <{\vspace{\tabcolsep}\end{minipage}}%   
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}

\arrayrulewidth=1pt
\tabcolsep=10pt
\arrayrulecolor{red}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}
{
|A{1.5}{\ratio{30}{100}}% 30%
|A{1}{\ratio{30}{100}}% 30%
|A{1.5}{\ratio{40}{100}}% 40%
|%
}\hline
%Cell 1,1


\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
A  & = \frac{\pi r^2}{2} \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \pi r^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}


The fundamental theorem of calculus,
\[
\int_a^b f(x)\,\textrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a)
\]
where \[\frac{\textrm{d}F(x)}{\textrm{d}x}=f(x)\]
&
%Cell 1,2
\LaTeX\ will make you confident! 
&
%Cell 1,3
\lipsum[1]
\tabularnewline\hline
%Cell 2,1
The fundamental theorem of calculus,
\[
\int_a^b f(x)\,\textrm{d}x=F(b)-F(a)
\]
where \[\frac{\textrm{d}F(x)}{\textrm{d}x}=f(x)\]
&
%Cell 2,2
\LaTeX\ will make you confident!
&
%Cell 2,3
\lipsum[2]
\tabularnewline\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you lose the `&` symbols, it works.  If you replace `equation` with `gather` you get a new error message (illegal `\par` detected).  I suspect that `longtable` is parsing the contents of environments, but not macros or `{...}` blocks.

```
{\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
A &= \frac{\pi r^2}{2} \\
 &= \frac{1}{2} \pi r^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}}
```

also works.

Comment: If I remove  "&" symbols
then I cannot align the equation however using one more  "{}" blocks
as you suggested solved my problem even though I am not totally sure why it solved the problem. 

Thanks..